# Jquery Selecting Form Items Conditional on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form and I want to disable all the Elements that do not match a given ID using jquery

here is the basic logic I'm trying to achieve

```
for (AllElementsInthisForm){

    if(formElementID != specificid)
    {
       disable
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [:not selector.](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('#FORMID input:not(#IDNAME)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Or an alternative sytax which is suitable for more complex conditions:

```
$('#FORMID input:not([id=IDNAME])').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wMUsg/

Comment: this can also be undone by using                            $('#FORMID input:not([id=IDNAME])').removeAttr('disabled');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form input:not(#excludeID)').attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A class would make more sense in your case.

```
<div class="disableThis" />
<a class="disableThis />

<script>
    $('.disableThis').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```